# Nesting Eloquent Queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to this Laravel Eloquent game and am getting a little stuck trying to create a query with dynamic variables set from another database.

I have one table named **articles**, where users can store articles and information about the articles. Users can group articles in magazines (table: **magazine**), each which can have multiple articles and which is associated with a user. Each article can be associated with multiple magazines

I'm trying to come up with a query that pulls the article_id of all the articles in a specific magazine and then uses the array of article_id to get an array of all information from **articles** that correspond to those article_id.

Help?!

EDIT 1:
Thanks for the feedback for a newbie. If you believe this has been answered before, I would appreciate some guidance into the right terms to search for.

The query that I tried to use was:

```
$mygazineQuery = (new UserMygazineArticles())->where('mygazine_id', $mygazineSearch);
foreach ($MygazineQuery AS $key => $val) {
    $MygazineQuery[$key] = (array)$val;
}
$codes = array_column($MygazineQuery, 'article_id');
$articles = Articles::whereIn('id', $codes)->get();

**Table UserMygazineArticles**
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articles_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mygazine_id` text NOT NULL,
  `saved` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: Can you precise what you have tried ?

Comment: please man, i answered such /similar questions a million time and so did others, check my recent answers and follow the same logic.

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja  Can you recommend the right search queries? I'm not sure I'm looking for the right thing.

Comment: @MasterDJon Thanks! This is the code that I ran first but it is coming back blank:
`$mygazineQuery = (new UserMygazineArticles())->where('mygazine_id', $mygazineSearch);

        foreach ($MygazineQuery AS $key=>$val)
        {
            $MygazineQuery[$key] = (array) $val;
        }

        $codes = array_column($MygazineQuery, 'article_id');

        $articles = Articles::whereIn('id', $codes)->get();`

Comment: Can you post the create statement ("show create table xxx") for the table behind UserMygazineArticles?

Comment: Sure, @herrjeh42: `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articles_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mygazine_id` text NOT NULL,
  `saved` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Comment: Please add these infos by editing the question. It's hard to follow like that. What I would in this question is : edit the question + add a comment stating I've edited it by stating the person I'm answering to.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @MasterDJon. Edited as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Eloquent you can join tables together. This is untested and based on assumptions how your tables look like in detail:

```
$query =  \DB::table('articles')->select("articles.*");
$query->join('user_articles_magazine', 'articles.id', '=', 'user_articles_magazine.articles_id');
$query->join('magazine', 'magazine.id', '=', 'user_articles_magazine.magazine_id');
$query->where('magazine.id', $magazineId);
return $query->get();
```

Comment: This gave me the direction to go! Thanks so much!